# XLForm Custom Row with Image and Text and Push Controller on Action Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xlform

I am using `XLForm` with `XLFormRowDescriptor`. Everything else is working fine but I have a requirement where I want to use custom row with Images and Text. In addition I need to do `XLFormRowDescriptorTypeSelectorPush` on the `XLFormRowDescriptor action`.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass from XLFormBaseCell (you can also create custom xib if you prefer to use IB), and implement

```
+ (void)load {    
    XLFormViewController.cellClassesForRowDescriptorTypes[@"YOUR_UNIQ_TYPE"] = NSStringFromClass([CHILD_OF_XLFormBaseCell class]);
}

- (void)configure {
    [super configure];
}

- (void)update {
    [super update];
}

+ (CGFloat)formDescriptorCellHeightForRowDescriptor:(XLFormRowDescriptor *)rowDescriptor;
```

To not use default actions (like XLFormRowDescriptorTypeSelectorPush) you can override this method:

```
- (void)formDescriptorCellDidSelectedWithFormController:(XLFormViewController *)controller {
//anything you want, for example
    if (self.rowDescriptor.action.formBlock) {
        self.rowDescriptor.action.formBlock(self.rowDescriptor);
    }
}
```

Then you will be able to create XLFormRowDescriptor using

```
- (instancetype)initWithTag:(NSString *)tag rowType:(NSString *)rowType title:(NSString *)title;
```